# Nginx - Two locations inside same server

Tags: nginx

I'm serving 2 Angular apps inside same server block, production and demo.

I created the folders /var/www/myapp/demo e /var/www/myapp/prod

So when I type localhost/ should be serve prod and locahost/demo serve demo

I try the following config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/myapp;

    location / {
        root /var/www/myapp/prod;
    }

    location /demo {        
        root /var/www/myapp/demo;
    }

}
```

And no success.

I trid others variations, but nothing until here

How can i configure my server block to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Remove both `location` blocks.

Comment: That way `http://localhost/` won't serve the `/var/www/myapp/prod` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In nginx, the path specified in `location` is added after the directory specified in `root`.

So, in this case nginx tries to load your demo version from `/var/www/myapp/demo/demo`.

This configuration should work provided that your configuration for the application server is correct in nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        root /var/www/myapp/prod;
    }

    location /demo {
        root /var/www/myapp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works and I undestood, thank you! Just one more question. And if serve /demo in another directory, like /dev?

Comment: Then you need to use `alias /var/www/myapp/dev;`